# Syndesis build error: Cannot access cluster for detecting mode

Tags: syndesis

When trying to build syndesis I got this error that prevents me to build the images:

```
[INFO] --- fabric8-maven-plugin:3.5.38:build (build) @ meta ---
[INFO] F8: Using OpenShift build with strategy S2I
[WARNING] F8: Cannot access cluster for detecting mode: Failure executing: GET at: https://192.168.42.178:8443/. Message: Unauthorized! Token may have expired! Please log-in again. Unauthorized.
[INFO] F8: Running generator spring-boot
[INFO] F8: spring-boot: Using Docker image fabric8/s2i-java:2.1 as base / builder
[WARNING] F8: Cannot access cluster for detecting mode: Failure executing: GET at: https://192.168.42.178:8443/. Message: Unauthorized! Token may have expired! Please log-in again. Unauthorized.
[ERROR] F8: Failed to execute the build [io.fabric8.kubernetes.client.DefaultKubernetesClient cannot be cast to 
io.fabric8.openshift.client.OpenShiftClient]
   ...
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal io.fabric8:fabric8-maven-plugin:3.5.38:build (build) on project meta: Failed to execute the build: io.fabric8.kubernetes.client.DefaultKubernetesClient cannot be cast to io.fabric8.openshift.client.OpenShiftClient -> [Help 1]
    ...
```

Command used to build syndesis: *syndesis build -i -f --clean-cache -c*

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is because you are logged out from the "oc" command. If you try to use it you will get errors like this one:

```
$ oc get pods
error: the server doesn't have a resource type "pods"
```

To fix it, you have to login again:

```
$ oc login
Authentication required for https://192.168.42.178:8443 (openshift)
Username: developer
Password: 
Login successful.

You have access to the following projects and can switch between them with 'oc project <projectname>':

    myproject
  * syndesis

Using project "syndesis".
```

If command "oc" is not recognized, you have to setup the environment first:

```
$ eval $(minishift oc-env)
```